# How to open existing cypress tests in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I open an existing cypress tests in cypress?
I have a project which already have some cypress tests but when I am installing cypress to get all the project's tests it is creating another cypress folder and never seeing the old projects tests?

Thank you

Zombie says in comments

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress"; 

export default defineConfig({ 
  chromeWebSecurity: false, 
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true, 
  env: { PASSWORD: "xxx", }, 
  e2e: { url: "xxx", }, 
});
```

Comment: Look for configuration files in the main folder. Perhaps you need to explicitly indicate the config file to open tests.
E.g.  npx cypress open --config-file=myconfig.config.js

Comment: Please explain the steps and show the folder structure + the cypress config file.

Comment: import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
  env: {
    PASSWORD: "xxx",
  },
  e2e: {
    url: "xxx",
  },
});
This is the config file
@lo

Comment: when i try npx cypress run --config-file=cypress.config.js it says:
Could not find a Cypress configuration file.

We looked but did not find a cypress.config.js file in this folder:...

Comment: the project does run in ci but does not open in cypress UI

Comment: and how Cypress is executed on CI?

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the current project will probably be an arduous task.

If I were you I'd create a **new blank project** with the latest Cypress, and move the tests across to it one by one.

- make a new folder
- decide if you want **typescript**, if so install it first
- install Cypress
- with **no tests or configuration, open Cypress GUI** and allow it to set up the folders and files for config and support
- **add the example spec** when it is offered, and run it - now your Cypress framework is active
- **compare the new config with your old one**, try not to copy anything that will break the new config, then run the example test again to make sure it still works
- copy across the simplest spec from old project,

  - test it,
  - repeat for the rest

Then you can raise **specific questions on SO** for each test that does not work, and there is no guesswork about what issues you might have in the old project.

Also, I would **add CI only after all tests are working locally**.

Comment: I have done that but now i am getting this error:
Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped
the tsconfig.json file is in the cypress folder but if i place it in the root folder of the project it does not show the error.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be in the cypress folder

Comment: My thinking is you will have one `tsconfig` at the root, since it's a Typescript project. You can have another in the cypress folder, but it must extend the root one. Or you can just have the root tsconfig by itself and add the Cypress types to it - your choice. The message about skipping paths refers to the `include` parameter - just add that into the tsconfig. This is kind of like answering a whole other question in a single comment, so you probably won't follow everything I said - but if you try it out you should be able to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are setting a TypeScript config file, but you are trying to run it as if it was JavaScript (from your comments: npx cypress run --config-file=cypress.config.**js**). If your app is JavaScript, you need to rewrite your configuration file. If the app is TypeScript, then you need to rename the configuration file as cypress.config.**ts**

Please, refer to https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration